# Подсчет слов и строк в файле - Java

Tags: java

Столкнулся с проблемой подсчета слов и строк из файла. Слова считает, а строки нет.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Problema005 {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        getWordCount();


    }

    public static void getWordCount() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        FileReader file = new FileReader(reader.readLine());
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        LineNumberReader lineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader(file);
        int counter1 = 0;
        int counter2 = 0;

        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            sc.next();
            counter1++;
        }

        while (lineNumberReader.readLine() != null){
            counter2++;
        }


        lineNumberReader.close();
        sc.close();
        reader.close();

        System.out.println("Number of words: " + counter1);
        System.out.println("Number of lines: " + counter2);
    }
}
```

На выходе считает слова, но не считает строки. Где ошибка?

Comment: покажу тебе сейчас современный способ прочтения файла. через 3-5 мин скину код

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот код. Если очень "сложный" - объясню (напиши об этом в комментарии).
Да, чтобы проверить, что код работает - создай файл "test.txt"

**Принцип работы:**

Файл поступает в фунцию `File` . Сканер читает фунцию `File`.

Далее создаем цикл. В цикле пишем на java `scanner.hasNextLine()` , что значит "пока существует следующая строчка в файле делай то, что указано далее".

Цикл открывается и файл считает первую строчку `lines++`. Далее я сокращаю 2-4 строчки кода в одну.

`String[] array = scanner.nextLine().split(" ")` - сканер считывает следующую строчк, потом с помощью функции `split(" ")` делит строчку на отдельные куски по пробелам и эти данные (они в виде одинароного массива) присваиваются массиву `array` .

**Примечание:**
так как строка была прочитана `scanner.nextLine()` - Сканер, при следующем прочтении будет читать следующую строчку, потому что данную строчку он УЖЕ прочел.

Пример сплит: `я написал этот код` после разделения `split(" ")` будут переданы массиву как `{я, написал, этот, код}`.

Далее прибаляем к `words` данные количества элементов в массиве - `array.length`

Далее цикл повторяется, а в конце выдает данные посчета.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class stackOver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

        getWordCount("test.txt");


    }

    public static void getWordCount(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException{
        File file = new File(filename);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        int words = 0;
        int lines = 0;

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            lines++;
            String[] array = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
            words = words + array.length;
        }

        System.out.println("Number of words: " + words);
        System.out.println("Number of lines: " + lines);
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое - работает. Можешь объяснить пожалуйста цикл while.

Comment: @Narione объяснил

Answer (score 2):

На Java 8 можно решить эту задачу красиво с использованием Stream API.

#### Вычисление за одно прочтение файла

**Вариант 1:**

Для вычисления обоих значений за одно прочтение файла, можно написать подобным образом:

```
Stream<String> lines1 =
    Files.lines(Paths.get("test.txt"));

int[] result = lines1
    .map(s -> Stream.of(s.split("\\W+")).
        filter(t -> !t.isEmpty())
        .toArray()
    )
    .map(ss -> new int[]{1, ss.length})
    .reduce(new int[2], (arr1, arr2) -> {
        arr1[0] += arr2[0];
        arr1[1] += arr2[1];
        return arr1;
    });

System.out.println("Number of lines: " + result[0]);
System.out.println("Number of words: " + result[1]);
```

Сначала читаем все строки в поток, разбиваем строки на отдельные слова, для каждой строки создаём пару `{1, число слов в строке}` и выполняем свёртку, суммируя по отдельности значения.

**Вариант 2:**

Но можно написать красивее, используя дополнительный метод:

```
private static <T> Predicate<T> predicate(Predicate<T> predicate) {
    return predicate;
}
```

и расширенные возвожности `LongStream` по сбору статистики:

```
LongSummaryStatistics statistics =
    lines1.mapToLong(s -> Stream.of(s.split("\\W+"))
        .filter(predicate(String::isEmpty).negate())
        .count()
    ).summaryStatistics();

System.out.println("Number of lines: " + statistics.getCount());
System.out.println("Number of words: " + statistics.getSum());
```

Здесь мы создаём поток с количеством слов в каждой строке и собираем по нему статистику - в данном случае нам нужно количество таких наборов слов (т.е. число строк) и сумма этих чисел (общее число слов).

#### Вычисление за два прочтения файла

Так как нельзя переиспользовать поток, можно прочитать файл дважды и вычислить значения в отдельности. Например, сначала получить общее число строк, что довольно просто:

```
Stream<String> lines2 =
    Files.lines(Paths.get("test.txt"));

long linesCount = lines2.count();
System.out.println("Number of lines: " + linesCount);
```

А за ещё один проход посчитать слова:

```
Stream<String> lines3 =
    Files.lines(Paths.get("test.txt"));

long wordsCount = lines3
    .flatMap(s -> Stream.of(s.split("\\W+")).filter(t -> !t.isEmpty()))
    .count();

System.out.println("Number of words: " + wordsCount);
```

Comment: Очень благодарен за примеры и объяснения!

Comment: @Narione добавил ещё один вариант для однократного прохода по файлу